# How can I check user input is valid and set an alert base on the input type?

Tags: angular

i have an input :

```
<input  #box1 (keyup.enter)="update(box1.value,2,item)" (keyup.enter) = "box1.value = ''" (click)="setStatus(select1.value)" style="width: 72px;text-align: center;border: 0px;" />
```

how can i check user input valid in typescript that user input must be number ?

I try to use pattern=[0-9] in html but that's fail, and i can use ngModule

Comment: Why not use Angular's reactive forms? This would save you having to write your own validation. Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms, and https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: I am new, formControl seem like level 2 to me. T_T
can you show me some code or reference webpage ?

Comment: The above comment includes 2 links to sites with many examples. It's very simple when you get your head around it and will save you lots of time.

Comment: use reactive forms for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive below code will help you to resolve your problem

**app.component.html**

```
<input #inp type="text" (keyup.enter) ="keyup(inp)" />
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  keyup(inp: HTMLInputElement) {
    let patt1 = /[0-9]/g;
    inp.value.match(patt1) !== null ? console.log(inp.value) : alert('this is NAN');
  }
}
```